# Define the concept of the Shape Operator and Fundamental Forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I am confused about the relationship between three concepts: shape operator, first fundamental form, second fundamental form.  I would like someone to provide me with a basic definition of these terms in the context of a specific example.

Consider a cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Let the axis of the cylinder coincide with the $z$-axis. Allow the cylinder to be paramterized as follows:
\begin{align*}
x(\varphi,h) &= a \cos \varphi \\
y(\varphi,h) &= a \sin \varphi \\
z(\varphi,h)&= h \\
\end{align*}
The metric $g$ for this surface is 
\begin{equation*}
g = \text{d}a^{2} + a^{2} \text{d}\varphi^{2} + \text{d}h^{2}
\end{equation*}

I don't understand what the three objects (stated in paragraph one) are so I am having trouble knowing how to compute them. Why do resources I have consulted talk about tangent vectors? I don't understand how that is necessary to define these concepts. If it is, can you explain why through this example?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
For those who read this in future and are similarly confused, I found the notes of Ted Shifrin resolved my questions --- at least so far as the points in the definition I was confused about.

So I regard this as answered.

Comment: You should look at some basic, elementary texts. Feel free to look at my notes, for example. You can download them from my webpage in my profile.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that and if that helps I'll remove the question.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, your Prof Shifrin! Cool! By the way, love your lectures. Thanks for sharing them on YouTube! The ones on alternating multilinear maps and forms were so helpful!

Comment: You don't need to remove the question, but I didn't want to give you a week's lecture in differential geometry :) And thanks.